# Calculate (or estimate) $S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(kx)}{k!}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Let $x\in\mathbb R$, $x>1$ and
$$S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(kx)}{k!}$$
where $\zeta(x)$ is the Riemann zeta function. Calculate (or estimate) $S(x)$.

Comment: See [OEIS A$76813$](http://oeis.org/A076813) and [OEIS A$93720$](http://oeis.org/A093720).

Comment: for $x > 1$ (where it is absolutely convergent) :  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(kx)}{k!} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{n^{-x}}-1)$

Comment: there is also 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(kx)}{ k!} =  x\int_1^\infty \lfloor y \rfloor e^{y^{-x}} y^{-1-x} dy$ from which you should be able to get precise bounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What one could do fairly easy (pure heuristics) is to obtain an expansion for large $x$. 
The Riemann Zeta function can be approximated in this limit by $\zeta(z)\sim 1+\frac{1}{2^z}$

Therefore our sum reads

> $$
> S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(kx)}{k!}\sim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{k! 2^{kx}}=e-2+e^{\frac{1}{2^x}}\sim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e-1+\frac{1}{2x}
> $$

which fits extremly well even for values as small as $x\approx 5$.

Because the Riemann Zeta function is monotonically decreasing for $z>1$ we might bound the series in question by simply estimating $\zeta(xk)<\zeta(x)$ to get

> $$
> (e-1)<S(x)<\zeta(x)(e-1)
> $$

which by the sandwich lemma yields the same big $x$ limit as above

I would be really surprised if an closed form for this series exists, but who knows...:)

Appendix:

By a very similar reasoning it is possible to get an approximation for $x\rightarrow 1_+$. It is well known, that in the vicinity of $z=1$ the Riemann Zeta function posseses an Laurent expansion of the form

$$
\zeta(z)\sim_{z\rightarrow 1_+}=\frac{1}{z-1}+\gamma
$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Marschoni constant. Therefore $S(x)$ is cleary dominated by the first term of the sum

$$
S(x)\sim_{x\rightarrow 1_+}\frac{1}{x-1}+\gamma+R(x)
$$

We might observe that the terms of the remainder $R(x)$ are given asymptotically by $ \zeta(k)/(k!)$ which is like $\gamma$ of $\mathcal{O}(1)$ . Therefore

> $$
> S(x)\sim_{x\rightarrow 1_+}\frac{1}{x-1}+\gamma+C
> $$

turns out to be a very good approximation in this limit ($C=\sum_2^{\infty}\zeta(k)/k!)$. Even if $x=1.5$ we are only of by something like $20\text{%}$

Comment: I did not know that $\zeta(z)\sim 1+\frac{1}{2^z}$ for $z\rightarrow \infty$. Could you tell me where I find the proof of this, please?

Comment: $\zeta(z)=1+\frac{1}{2^z}+\frac{1}{3^z}+\frac{1}{4^z}+.....$

which terms are the most relevant in the limit of big $z$? :)